# Javascript Array - adding a value to a particular key

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var all_area = [];
$.each(data,function(i,v){
    $.each(v.areas,function(a,b){
        all_area[i]['id'] = b.id;
        all_area[i]['name'] = b.name;
    });     
});
```

I want an array that has these data:

```
all_area[0]['id'] = 1;
all_area[0]['name'] = "test";
all_area[1]['id'] = 2;
all_area[1]['name'] = "test123";
```

My code is not working. I am getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`

This is the sample data that i am getting from my ajax call:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Dubai",
    "id": "1",
    "areas": [
      {
        "name": "Deira",
        "id": 1,
        "extra_fee": 0,
        "extra_time": 0,
        "min_order": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Bur Dubai",
        "id": 2,
        "extra_fee": 5,
        "extra_time": 10,
        "min_order": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Abu Dhabi",
    "id": "2",
    "areas": [
      {
        "name": "Shahama",
        "id": 3,
        "extra_fee": 0,
        "extra_time": 0,
        "min_order": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "City Center",
        "id": 4,
        "extra_fee": 5,
        "extra_time": 10,
        "min_order": 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add before inner `each`. `all_area[i] = {};`.

Comment: Can you add the value of `data` in question? There might be a better way to do the same thing.

Comment: `all_areas = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], data.map(v => v.areas))` - *possibly* a much more succinct way, depending on what the result needs to be exactly…

Comment: @Tushar I added sample data from my ajax call.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the object

```
$.each(v.areas,function(a,b){
    all_area[i] = {};
    all_area[i]['id'] = b.id;
    all_area[i]['name'] = b.name;
});
```

*OR*,

```
$.each(v.areas,function(a,b){
    all_area[i] = {
      id : b.id,
      name : b.name
    };
});
```

Comment: Should be above inner `each`. Otherwise, it'll override previous properties.

Comment: Possibly even more compact, depending on what `b` is exactly: `all_areas[i] = b`…

Comment: It might also be better to use `all_areas.push`, unless `i` is an important key…

Comment: @Satpal - this one is overriding previous properties. Thanks for the answer by the way.